# Rails NoMethodError in Albums#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror

I'm trying to show a link to a new description if an album doesn't currently have a description, but I keep getting a NoMethodError:

```
<% if @album.description.size = 0 %>
    <div class="new-description"><%= link_to 'Add Description', "/albums/#{x.id}/edit" %></div>
<% else %>
    <div class="description"><%= @album.description %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: look at your if condition it has only one = make it ==

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should also work, provided description is supposed to be a string.

```
<% if not @album.description.nil? %>
    <div class="new-description"><%= link_to 'Add Description', "/albums/#{x.id}/edit" %></div>
<% else %>
    <div class="description"><%= @album.description %></div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<% if @album.description.blank? %>
    <div class="new-description"><%= link_to 'Add Description', edit_album_path(@album) %></div>
<% else %>
    <div class="description"><%= @album.description %></div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Object#try`: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/be589a8b01500a4b52a86248458bf57597e568e8/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb

```
<% if @album.try(:description) %>
  <div class="description"><%= @album.description %></div>
<% else %>
  <div class="new-description"><%= link_to 'Add Description', "/albums/#{x.id}/edit" %></div>
<% end %>
```